# Creating / Appending a Flat File Destination based on date.

Tags: ssis

**The Backstory:**

I have a process that loads physician demographic data into our system. This data can come in at any time and at any interval between updates. The data is what we call "Term-by-Exclusion", meaning that the source file takes precedence, and any physician record in the db that is not in the source file is marked as "Termed" or Inactive.

**The Problem:**

I need to be able to output the data from the source data, into a flat file destination as a daily report to a companion COBOL system. The source data is loaded into an ETL.PhysicianLoad table prior to processing and the ETL table is wiped prior to each new processing transaction, so retaining a full days' records is not possible as it stands now, without the output file.

Example: ProcessOutput_10152013.txt

The output file ideally needs to be a comprehensive of the entire days' processing. Meaning I want to continuously append to that days' file until the end of that day, then email a notification stating the file is ready for pickup. Any data that comes in after the turn of the day should then be placed in newly created file.

Output should look like this (no headers)

```
BatchID | LastName | FirstName | MiddleInitial | Date
0001    | Smith    | John      | A             | 10/15/13
0001    | Smith    | Sue       | R             | 10/15/13
0001    | Zeller   | Frank     | L             | 10/15/13
0002    | Peters   | Paula     | D             | 10/15/13
0002    | Rivers   | Patrick   | E             | 10/15/13
0002    | Waters   | Oliver    | G             | 10/15/13
```

**What I am thinking:**

I am thinking about using a CurrentDate Variable that will hold the current date comparing it to an expression based variable called FileName which will concatenate the current mmddyyyy to "ProcessOutput_.txt". My thinking is that I should be able to locate a file with that name in the destination folder and if it exists, I should be able to write to it. Otherwise I will have to create a new file. I can then set my Flat File Destination via expression to the FileName Variable.

Can anyone see a better way of doing this or any issues that may arise from this solution I am not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thought process was in the right place, but flawed.

Here is how I solved the problem.

After trying to build my control/data flows using the logic in the original question, I discovered that I was working myself into a corner.

So that got me thinking again, how can I do this the easiest possible way

First, do I have the correct Variables defined? No..

- *CurrentDate* - has to be there to define the date portion of the file name.
- *FileName* - has to be present for obvious reasons.

So what did I miss?

- *FileExists* (Type: boolean) - Something that will identify the existence of the file.
- *PlaceholderFile* (Type: String) - Generic FileName Variable

Now what to do with it?

- Add a VB Script Task to the control flow, that sets the FileExists flag.

  ```
  'Check to see if ProspectivePhysician_<currentdate>.txt exists.
  Dts.Variables("User::FileExists").Value = File.Exists(Dts.Variables("User::FileName").Value.ToString)
  ```
- Now that we have the existence of the destination file defined, create the data flow object from the source table. Checking the FileExists Variable in a conditional split. Seperating the data flow into two branches. Create two Flat File Destinations called "Existing" and "New", setting them both to the same flat file location for the time being.

If you attempt to run the package at this point, you will receive Validation Errors from one of the two destinations, as the first is holding ownership of the file and will not allow the second to validate the file.

How to fix this...Use Expressions to swap the actual FileName value back and forth.

- For the Existing Flat File Connection String Value, use the following Expression:

  @[User::FileExists] == True  ? @[User::FileName]  :  @[User::PlaceholderFile]
- For the New Flat File Connection String value, use the following Expression:

  @[User::FileExists] == True  ? @[User::PlaceholderFile] : @[User::FileName]
- Finally, Right click on each of the Flat File Destination Objects in the Data Flow and set the Overwrite property to True on the New Flat File Destination, and False on the Existing Destination. This will assure that the Append action is used on the existing file.